# Oracle 10g Database recovery

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, data-recovery

I had an Oracle 10g installed on one primary server. It used to point to another server for storage. Now the primary server hard disk has crashed and hence I have lost all the oracle installation including control, parameter and archive log file. I still have the dbf file in secondary hard disk that contains data.

Now my question is how do I import the data from dbf file into another oracle installation.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, and you haven't given us any details, so I'll just say that the easiest recovery scenario when you only have datafiles is to [re-create the control file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5340551/3061852) using a new/empty Oracle instance.

Comment: I am not sure what are the details that you need. I can surely get you the details. Also a question about recreating control file. Should I just copy it from another instance of DB which is pointing to different data but same underlying schema.